Routing not working as expected in Angular 19
I have a login component as given below:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  showPassword: boolean = false;

  togglePasswordVisibility() {
    this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;
  }

  onSignIn() {
    console.log('Sign In:', { email: this.email, password: this.password });
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

  onSsoLogin() {
    console.log('SSO Login clicked');
  }
}  

This is my home component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.scss'
})
export class HomeComponent {

}  

This is my app.routes.ts:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent }, // Default route for login
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }, // Redirect any unmatched route to login
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];  

And this is login html code:
<button mat-flat-button class="button login-button" type="button" (click)="onSignIn()">
    Sign In
</button>  

But it is not routing to home component. What am I missing?

Since you have the wildcard route at the top of home, that is matched first, hence the problem, always define wildcard routes at the bottom of the route config, so that the proper route gets selected.
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent }, // Default route for login
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }, // <- to the bottom
];  


Missed that wildcard route... Thanks...

I have the same configuration like described here, but ** does redidrect to 404, but now since angular 19 404 is loaded first no matter what and after that the corect component, do you have any explaination?

@D4NT3 please replicate in stackblitz and share as a question for debugging

@NarenMurali this cannot be replicated on stackblitz since its an ssr issue, dev mode works as expected, it is the same example as above.

@D4NT3 it can be related to routing, guard, url mismatch anything, maybe turn on router debugging and validate it, we can also use stackblitz for ssr angular 19 ssr
